# Not remove directory of application when deploy new version AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a problem when I deploy my new application version the directory web/uploads is removed but it's not correct I want deploy without lose the upload.

I use symfony3 and the continous integration with git.

Do you have a solution ?

Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't be accepting file uploads directly to an Elastic Beanstalk server. Not only do the files get removed during a deployment, but any server failure would cause your server to be replaced with a version without the uploads. Also, uploading files directly to the server will prevent you from scaling your application beyond a single server. You should be storing uploaded files on S3.

Comment: It is possible to upload the image from my app to a S3 storage in PHP ? With aws sdk ?

Comment: Yes it's possible...

Comment: When you say "You should be storing uploaded files on S3" you think to another thing ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I suggest you do some research on using S3.

Comment: You don't think at upload with aws sdk ?  Is there an other solution ?

Comment: Yes, upload with the SDK.